# How to add two different properties of the same class to one POCO class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I have a class that has two references to one class (User):

```
public class Xpto {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Username2 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is EF only creates references to the first key (Username). That way User and User2 have Username as key and not what I intended...

I found this to be the answer:

[nHibernate, mapping two properties to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491455/nhibernate-mapping-two-properties-to-the-same-class)

But I wouldn't know how to apply this to my scenario.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Folks, nevermind... I guess I should've looked a little further.
The answer is here:
[How do I create a POCO object that has 2 references to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904796/how-do-i-create-a-poco-object-that-has-2-references-to-another-class?rq=1)

The standard is `<property_name><key_name>`
So the correct way would be **UserUsername** and **User2Username**

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the User class, please?

Comment: @DanielPersson It's a standard class with Username as [Key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the ForeignKeyAttribute instead, then you can select the names you like for your key attributes.

```
public class Xpto {

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User2")]
    public string Username2 { get; set; }

    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I found... System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema  Thanks, I'll do that way